# Linear fit predictions with changing values in R?

Tags: r

I've got some golf data that looks like this:

```
ID          round   GIR         score
Tiger Woods 3       0.666666667 68
Tiger Woods 2       0.611111111 75
Tiger Woods 1       0.666666667 71
Adam Scott  3       0.611111111 68
Adam Scott  2       0.888888889 68
Adam Scott  1       0.666666667 66
```

And I'm trying to make a linear model that says "based on greens in regulation, my round four score is going to be this."  Here's my script so far.

```
#load in data
gir2 <- read.csv("girforscore.csv")

#establish linear model
fit <- lm(score ~ GIR * ID, data = gir2)

#apply linear model
lmresultsGIR <- setNames(predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(ID = unique(gir2$ID), GIR = .6111111)), 
                      unique(gir2$ID))
#show model
head(lmresultsGIR, n=10)
```

My question is, assuming I have round 4 GIR data:

```
ID           round  GIR        
Tiger Woods  4      0.666666667 
Tiger Woods  4      0.611111111
```

how do I update my script to pick round 4 GIR data by ID, instead of just hardcoding a magic value of `.6111111` like I have now?

Comment: Are you sure that `predict()` works? You have `gir2$` in your model formula which usually messes with the prediction. You shouldn't have `$` in your formulas. I'm not sure I understand how you would choose te round 4 data which it doesn't exist. Are you trying to predict round 4 off the round 4 value?

Comment: @MrFlick, yeah, took out the `gir2$` in the fit function, just didn't update that in the question.  I'll do that now.  And yes, I'm trying to predict the round 4 score off of the round 4 value.  @nongkrong I don't know why I'd want GIR to be the mean value, what do you mean by that?

Comment: i dont get it, you have that data you shown in the end?  just use that as `newdata`

Comment: yeah @nongkrong I'm just not sure how to use that as `newdata`, if I understand you correctly

Comment: if it is in its own `data.frame` as indicated above called `ndat` for example, you can do `predict(fit, newdata=ndat)`

Answer (score 1):

Try giving this a shot.

```
#load in data
gir2 <- read.csv("girforscore.csv")

#establish linear model
model <- na.omit(gir2)
fit <- lm(score ~ ID + GIR, data = model)

#subset data for round 4
round4 <- subset(gir2, round == 4)

#apply linear model
predict <- predict(fit, newdata = round4, se.fit = TRUE)

#easier than setNames for this particular example
round4$score <- predict$fit

#view round 4 predicted scores
round4

ID round       GIR    score
7 Tiger Woods     4 0.6666667 71.29545
8 Tiger Woods     4 0.6111111 71.40909
```

Comment: Note that in this answer, the key function is `predict()`, and key argument is `newdata=`

Comment: @rbatt - I probably should have noted that the lm itself was modified as well